# change the selected tab in JTabbedPane "automatically"

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm using Java swing for the first time, and I have a problem which I can't solved.

I have a JTabbedPane with 3 tabs and I need to change to next tab "automatically" in the end of a computing, which starts with a click in a JButton (within one of the tabs).
I've tried to use `setSelectedIndex()` but doesn't work. 
After the JButton's `ActionEvent` the selected tab (printed in eclipse console) has changed, but in GUI doesn't had effect.

Yes, I've tried the `validate()`, `revalidate()` methods, even the `repaint()` method, but didn't work

That's an example of my code

```java
public class Tab1 extends JPanel {
    //when click on this button the computing starts
    JButton btn = new JButton("Compute...");
    btn.addActionListener(new BtnListener());
    add(btn);
}
```

An example of a JPanel which I'll add to my JTabbedPane

```java
public class Window() {

    private JFrame frame;

    public Window() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        JPanel tab1 = new Tab1();
        JPanel tab2 = new Tab2();
        JPanel tab3 = new Tab3();

        tabbedPane.addTab("tab 1", null, tab1, "tab1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("tab2", null, tab2, "tab2");
        tabbedPane.addTab("tab3", null, tab3, "tab3");

        //add() all components
    }
}
```

Example of my Window

```java
public class BtnListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        //make the computing
        //then I need to change to next tab (tab2)
    }
}
```

And my Listener

I hope you understand my problem.
Please help me, I really don't know what I do to make it works and I need to do this.

Comment: Read about multithreadin in swing here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch tabs you needn't to use `revalidate()/repaint()` just `setSelectedIndex()`.

Here is an example of switching to next tab:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    private JTabbedPane tabs;

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        tabs.addTab("1", new Tab(1));
        tabs.addTab("2", new Tab(2));
        tabs.addTab("3", new Tab(3));
        add(tabs);
    }

    private class Tab extends JPanel {

        public Tab(int i) {
            JButton next = new JButton("next");
            next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int selectedIndex = tabs.getSelectedIndex();
                    int nextIndex = selectedIndex == tabs.getTabCount()-1 ? 0 : selectedIndex+1;
                    tabs.setSelectedIndex(nextIndex);
                }
            });
            add(new JLabel("tab " + i));
            add(next);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think, author make huge computing in EDT. This is his/her mistake.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy may be you are right. But as written in `BtnListener` listener computes and then switch, this must work with some delay.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers.

I checked my code and I've found an instance problem. I was changing another instance of my Window instead of what was visible. So, when I fixed that, the updates worked.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A **change listener** is similar to a property change listener. A change listener is registered on an object — typically a component, but it could be another object, like a model — and the listener is notified when the object has changed. The big difference from a property change listener is that a *change listener is not notified of what has changed*, but simply that the source object has changed. Therefore, a change listener is most useful when it is only necessary to know when an object has changed in any way.

Similarly, you need to register a change listener on a button(or toggle button with states) to be informed when the calculation had stopped and the button's value changes.

```
//use some flag to determine when calculation process is actually finished
volatile boolean isCalculationEnds = true;  

button.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
 if (tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent() instanceof CustomPanel && isCalculationEnds) {
     //do something 
     }

 if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()==1 && isCalculationEnds){
   //do something
 });
```